# Merge in dplyr by a string variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like **primary** and a different like **secondary**:

```
library(dplyr)

primary <- data.frame(
  id = c("A123", "B456", "C789", "D012"),
  prod = c("1111", "2222", "3333", "4444"),
  d= c("USA", "CAN", "MEX", "BRA")
)

secondary <- data.frame(
  id= c("A123", "B456", "C789", "D012"),
  prod= c("1111", "2222", "3333", "4444"),
  rec_d = c("USA", "CAN,MEX", NA, "BRA")
)
```

I want to left_join(primary, secondary) by (id, prod) and also by checking if d is in rec_d.

I have tried the following code without success:

```
result <- left_join(primary, secondary, by = c("id", "prod")) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(d %in% rec_d| is.na(rec_d), 1, 0))
```

The desired outcome is:

```
desired <- structure(list(id = c("A123", "B456", "C789", "D012"), prod = c("1111", 
"2222", "3333", "4444"), d = c("USA", "CAN", "MEX", "BRA"), rec_d = c("USA", 
"CAN,MEX", NA, "BRA"), flag = c(1, 1, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Any clue?

Comment: Change your line to `ifelse(stringr::str_detect(rec_d, d) & !is.na(rec_d), 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

left_join(primary, secondary, by = c("id", "prod")) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(!is.na(rec_d) & str_detect(rec_d, d), 1, 0))

   id prod   d   rec_d flag
1 A123 1111 USA     USA    1
2 B456 2222 CAN CAN,MEX    1
3 C789 3333 MEX    <NA>    0
4 D012 4444 BRA     BRA    1
```

OR:

```
left_join(primary, secondary, by = c("id", "prod")) %>%
  mutate(flag = if_else(str_detect(rec_d, d), 1, 0, missing = 0))
```

Comment: i did not know the `missing` argument from `if_else`. This is definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr::case_when` with `.default = 0`. I feel it makes the mutate statement clearer than if_else with complex logical statements inside.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

left_join(primary, secondary, by = c("id", "prod")) |> 
    mutate(flag = case_when(str_detect(rec_d, d) ~ 1,
                            .default = 0
                            )
           )

    id prod   d   rec_d flag
1 A123 1111 USA     USA    1
2 B456 2222 CAN CAN,MEX    1
3 C789 3333 MEX    <NA>    0
4 D012 4444 BRA     BRA    1
```

Comment: No need of `case_when`. Squuze some speed out by coercion. ie `as.numeric(str_detect(rec_d, d))` or even `+str_detect(rec_d, d)`

Comment: That is not true, @Onyambu, as these would return `c(1,1,NA,1)` for the `flag` column, whereas the expected output is `c(1,1,0,1) `